# JS обработка нажатия enter во фрэйме с другого домена

Tags: javascript

Есть страница на сайте.
На странице стоит фрэйм, он занимает 100% высоты и ширины. По сути работаем мы с фрэймом, а не с окном, в котором он загружен.
С помощью JS общаться между страницей и фрэймом с другого домена нельзя.
Всё работает и основное окно нам, по сути, без надобности.

Но вот незадача - необходимо выполнить функцию (отправить сообщение) во фрэйме по нажатию ENTER.
Естественно при попытке "нажать кнопку" находящуюся во фрэйме из родительского окна с другого домена - появляется ошибка.

Как быть?
По факту то я нажимаю Enter находясь во фрэйме, но обрабатывается он всё равно родительской страницей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клавиатура обрабатывается тем фреймом, где сейчас *клавиатурный фокус*.

Напр., если добавить `<textarea>` в странице фрейма, и кликнуть в ней, то и последующие нажатия на клавиши будут обрабатываться этим фреймом, а не родительским окном.

[Тут пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369026/setting-focus-to-iframe-contents) про имитацию клика по таймеру для передачи фокуса, но это не сработает для кросс-домена.

Comment: Ваш комментарий мне помог. Я разобрался в проблеме.
Дело в том что на странице загружается фрэйм, да. Но, в этом фрэйме есть визуальный редактор, который из себя представляет ещё один фрэйм. Так вот функция отправки сообщения находится в первом фрэйме, и при нажатии на Enter (в тот момент когда курсор в поле для ввода, т.е. во втором фрэйме) происходила обработка путём window.top.add(). Но top обращается не к родительскому фрэйму, а к самому главному, я просто заменил top на parent (т.е. window.parent.add();) и всё работает:)